# I need help on my code, it gives me an error control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c, cs50

I am stuck in pset2 on cs50 , and honestly I think I am missing alot of stuff, I dont know if I can go forward in the course without being able to truely understand some basics. 
I am trying to get this done and then I think I will pause and still learn some basics about c. 
I need help with this as well as more commentary that I would be most grateful for.

so basically here's my code

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

bool crack(string given_hash);


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage ./crack hash\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!crack(argv[1]))
         return 1;
 }

bool crack(string given_hash)
{    
    string Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char key[6];
    char salt[3];
    salt[2] = '\0';

    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    {
        salt[x] = given_hash[x];
    }

    // single-letter keys.
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        key[0] = Alphabet[i], key[1] = '\0';
        string new_hash = crypt(key,salt);
        if (strcmp(new_hash, given_hash) == 0)
        {
            printf("you got the key: %s\n",key);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // for 2-letter keys.
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        key[0] = Alphabet[i], key[2] = '\0';
        for (int j = 0; j < 52; j++)
        {
            key[1] = Alphabet[j]; 
        }
        string new_hash = crypt(key,salt);
        if (strcmp(new_hash, given_hash) == 0)
        {
            printf("you got the key: %s\n",key);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // for 3-letter keys.
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        key[0] = Alphabet[i], key[3] = '\0';
        for (int j = 0; j < 52; j++)
        {
            key[1] = Alphabet[j];
            for (int k = 0; k < 52; k++)
            {
                key[2] = Alphabet[k];
            }
        }
        string new_hash = crypt(key,salt);
        if (strcmp(new_hash, given_hash) == 0)
        {
            printf("you got the key: %s\n",key);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // for 4-letter keys.
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        key[0] = Alphabet[i], key[4] = '\0';
        for (int j = 0; j < 52; j++)
        {
            key[1] = Alphabet[j];
            for (int k = 0; k < 52; k++)
            {
                key[2] = Alphabet[k];
                for( int l = 0; l < 52; l++)
                {
                    key[3] = Alphabet[l];
                }
            }
        }
        string new_hash = crypt(key,salt);
        if (strcmp(new_hash, given_hash) == 0)
        {
            printf("you got the key: %s\n",key);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // for 5-letter keys.
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        key[0] = Alphabet[i], key[5] = '\0';
        for (int j = 0; j < 52; j++)
        {
            key[1] = Alphabet[j];
            for (int k = 0; k < 52; k++)
            {
                key[2] = Alphabet[k];
                for(int l = 0; l < 52; l++)
                {
                    key[3] = Alphabet[l];
                    for(int m = 0; m < 52; m++)
                {
                    key[4] = Alphabet[m];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    string new_hash = crypt(key,salt);
    if (strcmp(new_hash, given_hash) == 0)
    {
        printf("you got the key: %s\n",key);
        return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

now I dont know what I am doing wrong , I know this error is due no no returning thing in a non void function, but how do I fix it ?

Comment: Your main function has 2 returns but they're both conditional on the if statements, i.e they might now get executed and your main function doesn't return anything then

Comment: thanks for the reply but the error is actually on the crack function , I would try to 'return 0;' on main and try again!

Comment: nope, nothing happened, error remained :'(

Comment: I just removed a brace from the end of the code you pasted, are you sure you dont have an extra one in your code or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error control may reach end of non-void function because the `crack()` function is suppose to return `bool` and there is no return statement in `crack()` function at the end. While compiling the code, the compiler found that all the return statements of `crack()` function can be reached *only* if some condition is satisfied

```
bool crack(string given_hash)

{    

    ....
    ....

    if (strcmp(new_hash, given_hash) == 0)
    {
        printf("you got the key: %s\n",key);
        return 0;
    }
    ....
    ....

    if (strcmp(new_hash, given_hash) == 0)
    {
        printf("you got the key: %s\n",key);
        return 0;
    }
    ....
    ....

    if (strcmp(new_hash, given_hash) == 0)
    {
        printf("you got the key: %s\n",key);
        return 0;
    }
    ....
    ....

    if (strcmp(new_hash, given_hash) == 0)
    {
        printf("you got the key: %s\n",key);
        return 0;
    }
    ....
    ....

    if (strcmp(new_hash, given_hash) == 0)
    {
        printf("you got the key: %s\n",key);
        return 0;
    }
}
      //<================ Return statement missing

}
```

and there is a possibility that the control may reach to end of function if none of the conditions is satisfied. You should add a return statement in the end of `crack()` function and return a value that indicates failure. Since in all cases you are returning `0` (seems that is for success case), may you can return `1` at the end to indicate failure:

```
    ....
    ....
    return 1;

}
```

---

Note that there is an exception for `main()` function, if control reaches the end of the `main()` function without encountering a return statement, `return 0;` is executed.

Comment: ok now that I could compile it, it doesnt return anything :'(

Comment: Read this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721336/5550963 carefully. It is in 99 and up that main always return 0.

Comment: @Gox My answer talks about `crack()` and not `main()`. For the `main()`, I have added a foot note in my answer. Check https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return and https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function

Answer (score 1):

Both your `main` and `crack` function have a code path that possibly reach then end of the function and will not return a value.

`main` - If crack returns `1` or `true` then the code will reach the end of main without returning an int value. There is however an exception for `main` that if you do not explicitly return then it will `return 0`. So while not a problem, I would still ensure that all code paths return.

`crack` - If none of your tests find a matching password hash then the function would reach the end and not return. Based on the function logic it would never happen, but the compiler does not know that.

To resolve the issue you need to ensure that all code paths return a value.

Comment: `main` does not. Any function in C/C++, `return 0` is implicit.

Comment: I meant main not any in above post. Actually, in C99 and up it return 0, in 89 and before it returns int but it is unknown what value does it have. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721336/5550963

Comment: @Gox _Any function in C/C++, return 0 is implicit._. No, it does not hold true for any function but only for `main()`.

Comment: @gox I think the confusion is in the wording of your first comment "Any function in C/C++, return 0 is implicit."

Comment: @Gox In your first comment you have mentioned - _Any function in C/C++, return 0 is implicit....._.

Comment: @H.S. that was my mistake. I apologize for it.